# Changing color and position for select list window

Tags: html, css

I want to program a select list with option who have gotten a value. But I want to change the position of the window which opens after I click on a option. Furthermore I want to change the color of the text in the window. How can I do that?

```
select id="targetField" onchange="alert(this.value)" multiple="multiple" name="D1" style="width:200px; line-height:27px; float:center; height:230px;">
        <option value="version:1.1 Test" style="color:green">Package</option>
```

This is what i have got right now.

```
select id="targetField" onchange="alert(this.value)" multiple="multiple" name="D1" style="width:200px; line-height:27px; float:center; height:230px;">
        <option <div class="test"> value="version:1.1 Test" style="color:green"</div>>Package</option>
```

I also tried this but it isn't working.

[image]

Comment: `float:center` ? Where did you find that ? :) . Anyway. It's not at all clear what you want to achieve. Please be more clear.

Comment: I work on a project with a group. so for examlpe float:center was made by a colleague. 
My goal is to change the color of the text and the Position of the window which opens, when you click on a option from a select list. right now it opens this "basic" window right in the middle of your screen @MihaiT

Comment: Can you reproduce that ( from the picture ) here in a code snippet? And whoever wrote `float: center` should not do it anymore :)

Comment: @MihaiT why shouldn't he do it anymore?:)
I am not quite sure if i understand you the right way. But this is the code snippet, which produces the "window" from the picture: `<select id="targetField" onchange="alert(this.value)" multiple="multiple" name="D1" style="width:200px; line-height:27px; float:center; height:230px;">
            <option value="version:1.1 Test" style="color:green">Package</option>`

Comment: `float:center;` does not exist in CSS. float can only have 4 values : left , right, none, inherit. To center an element there are other solutions available. Also, i meant that you should recreate your current situation in a `code snippet`. Edit your question and there is a button in the toolbar `<>` symbol. Use that.